# No error on missing fixtures in django unit test

Tags: django, unit-testing, error-handling, fixtures

Is there a way to see errors when django unit tests loads fixtures?

It's annoying that something like missing file, duplicate keys or  badly formatted fixtures files do not show up as error when running django unit test.

Answer (score 1):

If duplicate primary keys generated an error when a fixture was loaded, many existing tests would be broken. Sometimes a fixture needs to contain that error, so it can be tested against.

You can write generic tests to check for the problems you've mentioned:

- If your fixture fails to load, any query relying on that fixture will fail. Write a test that attempts to retrieve an object in that fixture (eg, `YourObject.objects.get(pk=1)` or `YourObject.objects.get(name='My Test Entry')`.
- To test if you have duplicate primary keys, compare `YourObject.objects.all().aggregate(Count('id', distinct=True))` to `YourObject.objects.all().aggregate(Count('id'))`. If those are not equal, you have duplicate primary keys.
- To avoid badly formatted fixture files, generate them from validated data. Use `manage.py dumpdata`, and avoid manually creating or editing fixtures.

The first test mentioned will indicate if you have an invalid path. The last recommendation removes any issues with bad formatting.

---

The silent failure is a result of how `loaddata` works. It's looking for the filenames given in the `fixtures = []` list in several locations, and may fail to find the files in any one of them. In order to report an error, `loaddata` must track if a file has been found yet, and that requires a patch. There's a [trac ticket for the silent fail](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10200), but it has been triaged at 'Design Decision Needed' for 2 years now.

You have the option to make some noise about this on the Django mailing list, and use [the unapproved patch](https://code.djangoproject.com/attachment/ticket/10200/scream-if-error-in-loaddata-command.diff) in your development copy of Django.

Comment: Those are all things I do when I think there might be a problem, but it doesn't point out the error itself. For multiple models and fixtures you would need lines and lines of check just to validate everything was loaded properly.

Comment: You're only checking the first item of a fixture to confirm it loaded. You could also see if it didn't load if you use the highest verbosity level when you run tests (-v 2), but then you'll see a great deal of other output too. I suggested using dumpdata so you'd avoid errors in the first place. The ridiculous method of checking each entry is the other option I suppose.

Comment: And just to clarify my stance, I don't think humans should ever need to edit serialized data. It's cruel to the individual, and leads to errors like the ones you're worried about. Just make it with dumpdata, and treat it like you would treat a bin.

Comment: I appreciate the help but badly formatted fixtures are only one possible problem and we do use dumpdata to generate our fixtures. Other possible problems are invalid path when specifying fixtures. I agree that all this can be fixed manually, but it's frustrating to lose time on these types of erros when a simple 'Fixtures not found' error or 'No Json object' error would tell the problem right away. Whatever the check you do to make sure a fixture was loaded properly will only tell you that it wasn't in case of an error.

Comment: Invalid paths are covered by the first test, and it is unlikely you will ever have bad formatting if you exclusively use dumpdata. I did some research on fixture loading and found your problem on Django's trac, and added this to the answer.

Comment: Problem with the test is that you would have to include at least for each fixtures loaded and you would still not know whether it's a format or path error. On the other hand you totally deserve the bounty for the research and help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to define your own validation method in setUp(). Testing if your fixtures are loaded would be quite easy, however, validating your fixtures would require quite a bit work depending on what format is your fixture.

Comment: Same as below. we do that already. Not interested in knowing if the fixtures are loaded, but to see the error that was generated when they failed loading.